# Neo4j Cypher - Creating relationship using two CSV files

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and I'm currently working on to build a citation network.

I have two CSV files one containing the node properties and other containing relationship properties.

PAPERS.CSV -

```
paperId, title, year
123, abc, 1900
234, cde, 1902
456, efg, 1904
```

CITES.CSV -

```
fromId, ToId
123, 234
234, 456
```

My graph should look like `(123)--cites-->(234)--cites-->(456)`.
Using these files how do I create a relationship between nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid space in the header names and in the data too.
If it is out of your control then you can use trim function and backticks to reference a headername. But normally, your csv should be clean.
Your files should be in the import directory of the neo4j. Otherwise you should comment out dbms.directories.import=import property in neo4j.conf.

You can create nodes like this:

```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///PAPERS.CSV" as line
   CREATE (p:Paper {paperId:trim(line.paperId), title: trim(line.` title`), year: trim(line.` year`)});
```

And you can create relationships like this:

```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///CITES.CSV" as line
   MATCH (p1:Paper {paperId:trim(line.fromId)})
   MATCH (p2:Paper {paperId:trim(line.` ToId`)})
   CREATE (p1)-[:CITES]->(p2);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works, but when I query `match (n) return (n)`.  I only can see nodes.  Is there any other query I should be using to see the entire graph with the relationships?

Comment: I think you should see relationships normally. If not, you can expand a node if you clock on it, and click on Expand child relationships. 
Or you can use this query: MATCH p=()-[r:CITES]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25