# how to build relationship between two different columns in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had set of questions and answers in a csv file as two columns . How can i build relationship between Question and Answer?

I had tried [Neo4j Cypher - Creating relationship using two CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755218/neo4j-cypher-creating-relationship-using-two-csv-files) this process but didn't get result.

My data looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to connect each `Question` and `Answer` node with a `HAS_ANSWER` relationship:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Test.csv" AS row
MERGE (q:Question {text: row.Question})
MERGE (a:Answer {text: row.Answer})
MERGE (q)-[:HAS_ANSWER]->(a)
```

[UPDATE 1]

And here is an example of getting the `Answer` to a specific `Question`:

```
MATCH (q:Question {text: "What is the square root of 4?"})-[:HAS_ANSWER]->(a:Answer)
RETURN q, a;
```

For faster results, you should create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) for `:Question(text)`.

[UPDATE 2]
To get a list of all the questions with the same answer:

```
MATCH (q:Question)-[:HAS_ANSWER]->(a:Answer {text: "The square roots of 4 are 2 and -2."})
RETURN a, COLLECT(q) AS questions;
```

For faster results, you should create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) for `:Answer(text)`.

Comment: thank you got it. can we retrieve answer for particular question.

Comment: can we find more frequently asked questions

Comment: My simple data model does not have a way to track the number of times a question was asked. You should try to come up with your own data model that supports that and ask a new question if it does not work.

Comment: my model is with  multiple questions as one answer. i am trying to retrieve  list of questions for  a answer. can it possible to find.

Comment: Seen Update 2 in my answer.

Comment: is it possible to retrieve answer for a new question( which is not in database.)  if it possible then how to give intelligence to retrieve answer for unknown question.

Comment: No. There is no magic :-). You have to add the question to the DB, and create a relationship between it and the answer -- then you can use the query I supplied.